# Create themed/skinned WPF FileDialogs

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I would like to have my own FileDialogs like OpenFileDialog,SaveFileDialog,BrowseDialog etc...

to skin them with the theme of my application to have a unique look/user experience.

Well I know I cant skin the win32 dialogs but what about creating my own file dialogs with a

window + tree for the folders and datagrid for the files. Would it be too much work to get

them safely working?

Comment: What are you asking, if this is possible? Of course it's possible. It's also a pretty major undertaking, since you should include as much functionality in the original boxes as possible (for example, did you know you can search for files by using the `*` and `?` characters?). You're better off just using the existing, standard Windows dialogs since it's something that users are most familiar with ("rolling your own" dialogs like this is discouraged for continuity's sake). Not to mention this question is an opinion, and can't really be answered concretely, and thus, doesn't have a place here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can create your own dialogs, which would give you the ability to skin them however you want.  As for whether it would be "too much work", I'd have to say that depends on your time/budget.  If the unique look is important to your design, then it is worth the time.

From a manager's viewpoint, I'd encourage you to finish the core application features first, to realize a return on investment on your work.  Most people, even with a skinned application, aren't terribly surprised by the common dialogs.  When you find yourself with extra time at the end of the project, you can allot some time to replace the common dialogs.

Good luck and hope that helps.